# window.CCapture is not a constructor in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I'm trying to load CCapture in Node.js instead of having to run a headless browser to record canvas stream. I keep getting window.CCapture is not a constructor error.

CCapture Library Link - https://github.com/spite/ccapture.js

Here is my code

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const { window } = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><body>
<script src='./node_modules/ccapture.js/build/CCapture.all.min.js'></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
</body>`,
// We need these options to allow JSDOM to require CCapture from node_modules
{ runScripts: "dangerously", resources: "usable" });
  
const document = window.document;

window.onload = () => {
        console.log("Onload >>>>>>");
        const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        //const canvas = createCanvas(200, 200)

        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "black", "white", "green"];

        function draw (){

            ctx.fillStyle = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }
        draw();

        
        var capturer = new window.CCapture( {
            format: 'ffmpegserver',
            framerate: 60,
            verbose: true,
            name: "foobar",     // videos will be named foobar-#.mp4, untitled if not set.
            extension: ".mp4",  // extension for file. default = ".mp4"
            codec: "mpeg4",     // this is an valid ffmpeg codec "mpeg4", "libx264", "flv1", etc...
                                // if not set ffmpeg guesses based on extension.
        } );

        console.log("Capture>>>>>", capturer);
   
  };
```

Comment: Log `window.CCapture` and see what you get.

Comment: @code I get `undefined`

Comment: I haven't used JSDOM before, but when you are calling the external script (in the JSDOM constructor) you're referencing `node_modules`. Are you sure you can access local files from script? Try importing via a CDN or using `file:///absolute/path/to/file`. It's not that `window.CCapture` isn't a constructor; it's that it's non-existent!

Comment: I checked the file stats of the directory. I'm getting information that the file exists

Comment: `stats>>>>> Stats {
  dev: 16777220,
  mode: 33188,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 501,
  gid: 20,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: 4096,
  ino: 83538372,
  size: 35077,
  blocks: 72,
  atimeMs: 1641537787550.764,
  mtimeMs: 499162500000,
  ctimeMs: 1641537687759.825,
  birthtimeMs: 499162500000,
  atime: 2022-01-07T06:43:07.551Z,
  mtime: 1985-10-26T08:15:00.000Z,
  ctime: 2022-01-07T06:41:27.760Z,
  birthtime: 1985-10-26T08:15:00.000Z
}`

Comment: Well, evidently the file was successfully imported; it's not a matter of the file existing. Try using a CDN.

Comment: That worked, awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.CCapture` returns undefined, which means the script wasn't loaded successfully.

That's because you can't import local scripts in such a way in JSDOM. One way to solve it is just to load the script via a CDN inside the JSDOM constructor argument instead of linking to a local file.

Answer (score 1):

jsdom can't resolve local paths..either use cdn or load the script inline by reading the file contents and then adding it to the dom via `document.createElement`

Sample:

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const fs = require("fs");
const script = fs.readFileSync("./node_modules/ccapture.js/build/CCapture.all.min.js", {
  encoding: "utf8",
  flag: "r",
});
const { window } = new JSDOM(
  `<!DOCTYPE html>
  <body>
  </body>`,
  {
    runScripts: "dangerously",
    resources: "usable",
  }
);
var document = window.document;
var scriptEl = document.createElement("script");
scriptEl.textContent = script;
document.head.appendChild(scriptEl);
window.onload = () => {
  console.log(window.CCapture);
};
```